# Get an 'Unexpected Kernel SDK Version'-error when running flutter project in android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

When I compile my flutter project in android studio for sdk x86 arm (mobile) i suddenly get this error below. Everything has worked fine untill now. Yesterday I upgraded flutter to newest version and there was no problems compiling the project after that. But suddenly today I get this error out of no where. Any idea what has happend? And what to do now?

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Unhandled exception:
Unexpected Kernel SDK Version 72c1995001 (expected 7c8c6b3053).
#0      BinaryBuilder._readAndVerifySdkHash (package:kernel/binary/ast_from_binary.dart:523:7)
#1      BinaryBuilder.readComponent.<anonymous closure> (package:kernel/binary/ast_from_binary.dart:555:7)
#2      Timeline.timeSync (dart:developer/timeline.dart:163:22)
#3      BinaryBuilder.readComponent (package:kernel/binary/ast_from_binary.dart:539:21)
#4      IncrementalCompiler.prepareSummary (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart:1647:12)
#5      IncrementalCompiler.ensurePlatformAndInitialize (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart:1138:23)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      IncrementalCompiler.computeDelta.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart:229:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      IncrementalCompiler.compile (package:vm/incremental_compiler.dart:69:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:509:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      listenAndCompile.<anonymous closure> (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:1105:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.
the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.
```

this is the output of flutter doctor:

```
/Users/thanos/Desktop/Development/flutter_2_0_1/bin/flutter doctor --verbose
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.5, on macOS 11.2.3 20D91 darwin-x64, locale da-DK)
    • Flutter version 2.0.5 at /Users/thanos/Desktop/Development/flutter_2_0_1
    • Framework revision adc687823a (10 days ago), 2021-04-16 09:40:20 -0700
    • Engine revision b09f014e96
    • Dart version 2.12.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/thanos/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/thanos/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • sdk gphone x86 arm (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
    • Chrome (web)                • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 90.0.4430.85

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had a similar issue, was able to fix it by just deleting the cache folder in flutter/bin and then running flutter doctor.

Comment: Thanks.. actually solved this a long while ago, can¨t remember what I did tho' :D

Answer (score 1):

I solve this with CMD and type "choco upgrade dart-sdk"

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when programming with dart in vscode and all it took me to solve was to reinstall the dart sdk package via chocolatey.

1. Open windows powershell as an admin;
2. run 'choco install dart-sdk --force';
3. Pray that it will work. (jk it probably will)